# POST request throwing an error saying that HttpRequest is not returned

Tags: django

In my django forms.py, I have following class, as you can see if the request is POST I just want to print the firstname entered by the user. When i execute this code, it is throwing the following error

> The view home.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It
>   returned None instead.

```
def register(request):

 if(request.method == 'POST'):
  form = SignupForm(request.POST)
  if(form.is_valid()):
     firstname = request.POST['firstname']
     latname = request.POST['lastname']
     email = request.POST['email']
     password = request.POST['password']
     confirmpassword = request.POST['password2']
     country = request.POST['country']
     return HttpResponse("firstname" + firstname)
 else: 
   form = SignupForm()
   return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank  you very much for the attention.

Comment: Hint: what does your code do if the request is not POST?

Comment: Are you trying to say that I need to sent the new html for displaying the firstname with the HttpResponse.  'register.html' dont have the code to display the value of firstname.

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all. When you first request the page, you need to display the empty form; that is a GET, which your code does not handle. You can fix that with a simple change: move the last line back one indent, so it is called in all cases.

Comment: Thanks. It is like that only in the eclipse. may be it is appearing differently due to the formatting of the SO

Answer (score 0):

The last `return` statement of your view is inside the `else` block. Moving it outside of `else` block should fix the error:

```
def register(request):
    ...
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})
```